# Unknown error "-1073741823"

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications

[image]I am developing a webapplication with forms authentication enable.
**I am getting this error in IIS8(Production) but not in IIS7(Test Environment)**

Please let me know for more information. App Pool settings , authentication settings are looks fine.

```
CryptographicException: Unknown error "-1073741823".]
System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptNative.OpenAlgorithm(String algorithm, String implementation) +5919869 
System.Security.Cryptography.BCryptHashAlgorithm..ctor(CngAlgorithm algorithm,     String implementation) +231   
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng..ctor() +174
System.Web.UI.EventValidationStore.Hash(String target, String argument) +151
System.Web.UI.DefaultEventValidationProvider.TryLoadEventValidationField(Object eventValidationField) +94
System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.EnsureEventValidationFieldLoaded() +298
System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +80
System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +80
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +574
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2773
```

Comment: Perhaps this can shed some light: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22826636/Error-code-1073741823-0xC0000001.html

Comment: @PeterB Thank you!, Is there any other way to identify ? Just noticed there is a event logged in event viewer.Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 

Event ID: 00d6a946c0c342a6a1e234411eb36792 
Event sequence: 62 
Event occurrence: 18 
Event detail code: 0Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred.

Comment: Sorry, I really wouldn't know. One thing to try: check if the server has all the latest updates. Perhaps it's running on an older version of something.